# Task Parallel Library Exception handle "A task was canceled."

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a method as:

```
var taskCount = Task<List<Client>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            {

return ClientRepository.GetListAll();
                            }).LogExceptions<Client>();
count = taskCount.Result;
```

I have extension method as LogException as:

```
public static Task<T> LogExceptions<T>(this Task<T> task) where T : new()
        {
            return task.ContinueWith<T>((antecedent) =>
            {
                bool isError = false;
                var aggException = antecedent.Exception.Flatten();
                foreach (var exception in aggException.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    isError = true;
                    LogWrite.LogStep(" Task Exception - ", exception.Message);
                }
                if (isError)
                {
                    return new T();
                }
                else
                {
                    return antecedent.Result;
                }
            },
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
        }
```

The above code works fine if any exception occurs, it handles the exception and prevent worker process from shutting it down.

But when there is no error, it just returned with aggregate exception as "A task was canceled". Not sure what am I doing wrong in the above code.

if above code is wrong then what would be the best way to handle exception in a task in a generic way.

Comment: can you check the inner exception of aggregate exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your `TaskContinuationOptions` selection of `OnlyOnFaulted` in the continuation. Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `OnlyOnFaulted` indicates the continuation will only occur if the preceding task throws an unhandled exception. Since you aren't getting an exception in all scenarios, the continuation is not working properly. Try omitting the `TaskContinuationOptions` parameter or using the default enum value of `None`.

Comment: Aaahh, I got it.. Thanks @ledButter you saved my day.. everything works fine if i removed that TaskContinuationOption and it make sense as well.. Atleast my understanding on TaskContinuationOption  is clear now...High five:)..

Comment: cant up vote your answer as I required 15 reputation and I'm new to this community. But its really an excellent answer and I'm sure there are many who might  have faced problem like me. No one has explained it before in stack exchange or may be I didn't find any when I searched before posting this question...You are the best..